# Multiple single field indexes vs multiple-fields indexes

Tags: sql, sqlite

I know there are similar questions on StackOverflow, but after testing different indexes on my tables, I think I don't quite understand how indexes work and I'd like it if someone could explain the behavior I'm experiencing on my queries' performance.

I'm using this query as an example, I'm going to try to explain it in detail:

```
 SELECT ss1.PlayerID, ss1.Name, ss1.Series, ss1.LanesNum, ss1.Date, ss1.LeagueName, ss1.Season FROM SeriesScores ss1
          JOIN (SELECT Series, Gender, LanesNum, Bowlout, Season FROM SeriesScores
          WHERE Gender = ? AND LanesNum = ? AND Series > -1 AND Bowlout = 'No' AND Season = '2011-2012'
          ORDER BY Series DESC LIMIT 0,?) as ss2
          USING(series, gender, lanesNum, bowlout, season)
          ORDER BY ss1.Series DESC
```

This query is used to get the highest series bowled in a given season for each pair of lanes in a bowling center for both male and female players.

I'm joining the table on itself instead of using the MAX aggregate function because if there's a tie on a given pair of lanes, I want all the names to come up.

Basically, I join all the fields that match what the inner SELECT returns. That inner SELECT returns the top X players for a given gender and a given pair of lanes.

The USING part makes sure only the players that haven't bowled out, with the same gender, series, lanesNum and season as I'm looking for get selected. I then order them by highest series to lowest series.

This query is in a for loop, which gets run 12 times for men and 12 times for women (12 pair of lanes in the bowling center) with only the lanesNum and gender parameters changing.

I then put all the results in two different vectors in Java to display the results in an application (one vector for men, one for women).

Without any indexes whatsoever, it takes around 11 seconds to run everything including putting the results in a vector and all of that. (5.5 seconds for the 12 queries for men, same for women).

With an index on (gender, lanesNum, series), it takes 0.04 seconds for the whole thing, which is amazing, since that's a more than acceptable speed for my needs.

I used that index because those are all the most important fields I'm using in my WHERE clause, but I don't get why it speeds things up that much, because I tried other things and using some other indexes actually made my queries SLOWER by more than 100%. Also, I'm wondering if I would get an even faster query if I added "bowlout" and "season" to that index.

I wanted to try a single column index on series first and test performance. That's the index that made all of those queries take a total of 22 seconds.

I came to the conclusion that I don't understand where I should be using my indexes and when I should be using them on multiple fields, or using multiple indexes on single fields, etc. Also, I don't understand how using (the wrong) indexes can actually make performance worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizing an index too aggresively for just one query runs the risk of slowing down other queries (and thus a real world application, or the next version of it).  However, let us do exactly that as an exercise in analysing index performance.

Indexes influence query performance in multiple ways; their existence can actually completely change the algorithm that the database server will use to get to the data.  A nice overview is [here](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html), but as your query is simple, and you actually have very few relevant indexes in your database (the one you see, and also automatically created indexes to support the primary keys of your tables) we can simplify the story greatly.

A good index makes it faster to cross reference the data between the tables.  Ideally it contains columns in your USING and WHERE clauses, and enough of them to reference a unique row in its table most of the time.  If it contains less, it may still be used by the database server, but the remaining rows will have to be visited one by one.

An great index does not only all that, but it also contains all data that you will be selecting from the table (yes, this makes sense when the two tables are actually the same physical table due to the self-join; the database server still processes as if it was two different tables, incidentally with the same data).  The benefit of such a "fully covering index" is that the database server does not have to visit its table at all; all the columns are available in the index.

Order of columns in the index matters.  It is especially essential that the leftmost column in the index appears in the USING clause, or WHERE clause; otherwise the index is pretty much unusable as matching data for a single lookup can appear in many locations in that index.  It should also be highly selective (have many different values in the table). Do a few experiments now to see this first hand.

For this reason, the first choice index I'd suggest to you would be `series, gender, lanesNum, bowlout`; but yours is also a very good one for this query.

There is not much use in creating more than one index explicitly.  There is basically no use for more than one of them during query execution, because your query is so simple.  So the most useful one will supposedly win and all the others will be ignored.

To your last question: some people believe that superfluous indexes only slow down UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE statements (because these carry the overhead to update the indexes), but it is not that simple.  As the database server considers multiple algorithms to compute your query (there are two logical tables to start from and automatic and explicit indexes to use, or not to use), it may choose the wrong plan: an index may look seductive without knowing the data distribution in the table, but be very counterproductive given the distribution.

There is actually a way to let the database server analyze the data and record some statistics that will greatly help it optimize your subsequent queries reasonably and probably to avoid any 22 second executions of your query (until you change your data so much that the statistics will no longer hold true).  That is the ANALYZE command.  Issue it every time after you change your indexes to see the subsequent sqlite performance at its best.  In a production database, schedule ANALYZE to execute every night, so that your database does not gradually slow down over time, or abruptly after adding a harmless, useless index.

Comment: Very clear and detailed answer, thanks! Just a quick question about when you say there is not much use to creating other indexes because this query is simple... Since I have other (sometimes more complicated) queries, would adding indexes for those other queries using the same table be beneficial or could it slow down this query if the database thinks it should use the other index instead? Other than that I think I get everything, thanks a ton!

Comment: As I said in the beginning, this was a single query mental exercise only.  Once you have multiple queries, you will want decent performance for all of them.  You will often want to have a single index per table that can serve all of them, but not necessarily.  Once your statistics are uptodate, an additional index should not cause a slowdown, except during the very first execution of the query, or when the query optimizer itself fails to do a superb job.

Comment: @Adam - The extremely small slowdown during the first execution I refer to in a previous comment is for the query optimizer evaluating various algorithms it could use to evaluate your query.  After that, the winning algorithm (so called query plan) is reused for identical queries.

Comment: Thank you, it clears things up, I'll try to keep everything you mentioned in mind. I wish I had known all of that beforehand :)